# Output elements from an array in reverse order

Tags: c, for-loop, reverse

Im trying to get the program to output the numbers 1,2,3,4 in reverse order.
However, I keep getting strange results and am not sure why.
This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NO_OF_ELEMENTS 4

int main()
{
    int numbers[NO_OF_ELEMENTS];
    int i, j;

    printf("Type a number and hit enter:\n");

    /* Input each number */
    for(i = 0; i < NO_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    }

    /* Print each number in reverse order */
    for(j = NO_OF_ELEMENTS; j > 0; j--)
    {
        printf("%d\n", &numbers[j]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

The output of the program looks as follows:

[image: Program Running]

Any help in explaining why the code doesn't work as I expect it to will be greatly appreciated.

**FIXED**

```
/* Print each number in reverse order */
for(j = NO_OF_ELEMENTS; j > 0; j--)
{
    printf("%d\n", numbers[j - 1]);

}
```

[image]

Comment: It's just `numbers[j]` in `printf`; no `&`. And your index is off by one, so `numbers[j - 1]`.

Comment: @melpomene I think it is the `scanf` in the for loop. An answer is provided in that link. Is that wrong? Your answer comment is correct.

Comment: @Elyasin The question you linked is about `scanf` seemingly skipping input. That's not the case here: OP was able to enter 4 numbers as expected.

Comment: melpomene is right. Drop the `&` from the printf. It currently prints the address of the variable, not its value.

Comment: I don't know what compiler you're using, but gcc can warn you about mistakes like this (at least with suitable warning options enabled).

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: @melpomene I am using the GCC GNU C/C++ compiler with code:blocks and it doesnt like it when i remove & from printf

Comment: @eamonn-keogh "doesn't like it" is not a problem description.

Comment: @melpomene The program crashes if I don't use &

Thanks for the help it got it working as expected. Its within the 2nd for loop printf statement where you remove & and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For `printf` you doesn't need `&`, remove it and it would works.

And the second for you need start at `NO_OF_ELEMENTS - 1` because of array start at `0` and ends at `3` for 4 items.

[image]

Comment: It isn't a text editor, is Konsole, a terminal emulator for KDE desktop environment. To code I use Webstorm and Vim.